# Appropriate Oracle download for hibernate-dialect org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect

Tags: spring, oracle, hibernate, legacy

I am altering a legacy software implemented with java spring. Now the challenge is I want to determine the appropriate Database that was used during the initial development.
I have seen somewhere on the code that that the hibernate dialect was `org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle9Dialect`
So i want to use that piece information to determine which version of oracle to install.

Please i am new to Oracle, So a link to an appropriate url will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

9 is an older version of Oracle Database that is no longer supported, and it is no longer available for download from [Oracle's Database Software Downloads](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/index.html) page. The [Oracle9Dialect was deprecated](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/CWD-1039) back in 2008, so I wish you the best of luck with your legacy work because I'm sure it is long overdue.

You can request version 9 from Oracle if you have a valid Oracle Database product license (any version,) but if you do not, your options will likely only be third party hosts or acquiring installation media for version 9 by some other means. If you are working with an organization that has you supporting this legacy software, you may have some luck looking through old installation media or asking someone who has been with the company for a while.

From Oracle (bottom of Database Software Downloads page):

> Oracle Database 10.2 and 11.1 are no longer available for download. The software is available as a media or FTP request for those customers who own a valid Oracle Database product license for any edition. To request access to these releases, follow the instructions in Oracle Support Document 1071023.1 (Requesting Physical Shipment or Download URL for Software Media) from My Oracle Support. NOTE: for Oracle Database 10.2, you should request 10.2.0.1 even if you want to install a later patch set. Once you install 10.2.0.1 you can then apply any 10.2 patch set. Similarly, for 11.1 request 11.1.0.6 which must be applied before installing 11.1.0.7. Patch sets can be downloaded from the Patches and Updates tab on My Oracle Support.

Comment: This implies that oracle 9 is actually the version that is appropriate for that dialect. Thank you, i will explore my options

Comment: Well, Yes and No. Oracle9Dialect was the version released with Oracle Database 9, however, Oracle supports backwards compatibility. It's possible that the database was a later version (like 10g,) and the team responsible for the Legacy software you're now supporting simply continued using the deprecated Oracle9Dialect instead of updating to Oracle9iDialect or Oracle10gDialect. It's not uncommon for dev teams to continue using older/outdated drivers, dialects, etc. Oracle9Dialect released with Oracle Database version 9, but that does not mean the software necessarily used a 9/9i database.

Comment: It's probably safe to assume that it was a 9 database, but it's possible that the database was a later version and the dev team simply used an earlier Dialect. Just a small bit of clarification if you happen to run into issues - if you can't get it working with a 9/9i database, you might want to try creating a 10g database to see if that works better.